# Which book had a character enclosed in an asylum, formerly abattoir worker, that somehow may have had alien contact?

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I read decades ago a UK book, I believe (I distinctly remember the word abattoir, I believe a US book would say slaughterhouse, but I might be wrong), that is mostly a psychological/psychiatric drama not unlike *12 Monkeys*, then again it would not have been the *12 Monkeys* script or something. We are presented with an apparently highly psychotic individual hospitalised, who reports meetings/talks with aliens/angels/spirits, and we get to know that he broke down mentally after years of working at an abattoir, but somehow by the books conclusion we are led to believe the aliens/angels were true all along.

Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question to see if that helps elicit more details for your question. More details gives us more chance to help you.

Answer (score 2):

While it doesn't fit the use of abattoir versus slaughterhouse, is there any chance you're thinking of Kurt Vonnegut's *[Slaughterhouse-Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slaughterhouse-Five)*?

> The story is told in a non-linear order, and events become clear through flashbacks and time travel experiences from the unreliable narrator. The narrator describes the stories of Billy Pilgrim, an American man from the fictional town of Ilium, New York who believes he was held in an alien zoo on the fictional planet of Tralfamadore and has experienced time travel.
>
> As a chaplain's assistant in the United States Army during World War II, Billy is an ill-trained, disoriented, and fatalistic American soldier who finds he does not like war and refuses to fight. He is captured in 1944 by the Germans during the Battle of the Bulge. Billy nearly dies due to a string of events. Before he is captured, he meets Roland Weary, a patriot, warmonger, and sadistic bully who derides Billy's cowardice. When the two are captured, the Germans confiscate everything Weary has and force him to wear painful wooden clogs. Weary eventually succumbs to gangrene caused by wounds from the stiff clogs. While dying in a rail car full of prisoners, Weary convinces fellow soldier Paul Lazzaro that Billy is to blame for his death. Lazzaro vows to avenge Weary's death by killing Billy, because revenge is "the sweetest thing in life".
>
> At this moment, Billy becomes "unstuck in time" and has flashbacks from his former life. Billy and the other prisoners are transported by the Germans to Luxembourg. By 1945, the prisoners have arrived in the German city of Dresden to work in "contract labor" (forced labor). The Germans hold Billy and his fellow prisoners in an empty slaughterhouse called Schlachthof-fünf ("slaughterhouse five"). During the extensive bombing of Dresden by the Allies, German guards hide with the prisoners in the slaughterhouse, which is partially underground and well-protected from the damage on the surface. As a result, they are among the few survivors of the firestorm that rages in the city between February 13 and 15, 1945. After V-E Day in May 1945, Billy is transferred to the United States and receives his honorable discharge in July 1945.
>
> Soon, Billy is hospitalized with symptoms similar to post-traumatic stress disorder and placed under psychiatric care. There, he shares a room with Eliot Rosewater, who introduces Billy to the novels of the obscure science fiction author Kilgore Trout. After his release, Billy marries Valencia Merble, whose father owns the Ilium School of Optometry that Billy later attends. Billy becomes a successful and wealthy optometrist. In 1947, Billy and Valencia's first child, Robert, is born, and two years later their daughter Barbara is born. On Barbara's wedding night, Billy is captured by an alien spaceship and taken to a planet many light-years away from Earth called Tralfamadore. The Tralfamadorians are described as being able to see in four dimensions, simultaneously observing all points in the space-time continuum. They universally adopt a fatalistic worldview: death means nothing to them, and their common response to hearing about death is "so it goes".

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with Kurt's other works, so on account of that abattoir thing and the "fact" I would have remembered one of Tom Robbins' favorites, I don't think it's that but worth rechecking on my part! Maybe one of those semi-legal "influenced by" works!